# Плавающий блок - как убрать фиксацию?

Tags: html, javascript

Вот  [мой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2ErnB/2/) залипающего блока. По достижению нижней границы таблицы `table` хотелось бы, чтобы фиксация исчезла.

Код фиксации:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Фиксация

  var $window = $(window),
  $navigation = $(".navigation");

  $window.scroll(function() {
    if (!$navigation.hasClass("fixed") && ($window.scrollTop() > $navigation.offset().top)) {
        $navigation.addClass("fixed").data("top", $navigation.offset().top);
    }
    else if ($navigation.hasClass("fixed") && ($window.scrollTop() < $navigation.data("top"))) {
        $navigation.removeClass("fixed");
    }
  }); 
});
```

Как это сделать в пределах `.wrap`? Кто поможет?

upd: [новый пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2ErnB/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется мне удалось сделать по проще:

```
var navbar =  $('.navigation');  // navigation block
var wrapper = $('.wrap');        // may be: navbar.parent();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var nsc = $(document).scrollTop();
    var bp1 = wrapper.offset().top;
    var bp2 = bp1 + wrapper.outerHeight()-$(window).height();

    if (nsc>bp1) {  navbar.css('position','fixed'); }
    else { navbar.css('position','absolute'); }
    if (nsc>bp2) { navbar.css('top', bp2-nsc); }
    else { navbar.css('top', '0'); }
});
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/wXFB9/
(обновлено)

По сути всё сводится к этому:

```
if (nsc>bp1) { /* достигнут верх враппера */ }
if (nsc>bp2) { /* достигнут низ враппера */  }
```

Comment: @Олег Б, у вас, конечно, как всегда хорошее решение, но мне нужно, чтобы именно как у меня было, т.е. шапка и футер не задействовались, а залипание происходило в пределах `wrap`. Вот новый пример, поточнее - http://jsfiddle.net/2ErnB/3/. Как тут узнать, что достигнут низ врапера и отлепить блок?

Comment: Посмотрите это: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/wXFB9/ сделал на вашей разметке + убрал отсчет координат веду от .wrap без всяких футеров, и хедеров.  Если не то, значит я не могу никак догнать задачу.

P.S> В jsfiddle не стоит писать такие вещи как: ``$(document).ready(function(){ }));`` и ``<script></script>`` он подставляет их автоматически.

Comment: @Олег Б, здорово и просто. спасибо за помощь! :)

Answer (score 0):

Решал подобную задачу, посмотри сайт transyslygi.ru
Там есть скрипт, набери transyslygi.ru/script.js 
В нем есть функция window.onscroll = function().
В ней я сделал условие прилипания сайдбара, а по достижению подвала, сайдбар отлипал

Comment: спасибо, но у вас там строго заданная высота хедера, после которой начинает залипать и высота футера, перед которой начинает отлипать, а мне нужно только в пределах блока `wrap`.