# Фиксирование блока на определенном месте при прокрутке

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, нужно блок фиксировать при прокрутке, когда top==165; делаю так:

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 165) {
   $('#view .fltrow').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '165px', 'z-index':'999'});
  } else {
   $('#view .fltrow').attr('style','');
  }
 });
```

у меня получается, что блок при прокрутке доходит до top==0 потом резко фиксируется на top==165(будто ощущение что прыгает), а мне нужно, чтоб блок не доходил до top:0;  а именно на top 165 сразу фиксировалась, как достичь такого результата, в гугле не могу найти материалов, подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давно делал подобный пример: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/wXFB9/
он так-же является ответом на этот вопрос: [Плавающий блок - как убрать фиксацию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/271912/html-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Посмотрите мб вам подойдёт.

Comment: спасибо, но мне нужно фиксировать не на top:0  как у вас там сделано а на top:165