# Как ограничить прокрутку блока?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день. Есть див, который прилипает к верху страницы, но при прокрутке залазит на футтер. Как можно ограничить его прокрутку, может, указать высоту или как-то сказать ему стоп? Помогите, пожалуйста. Вот схематический рисунок, как должно быть:

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var search_bar = $('#my_search_bar');

  var margin = 15;

  var borderY = search_bar.offset().top - margin;

  $(window).bind('scroll', function()
  {
    var currentY = $(document).scrollTop();

    if(currentY > borderY)

    {
      search_bar.css({position: 'fixed', top: margin + 'px'});
    } 

    else if(currentY < borderY)

    {

      search_bar.css({position: '', top: ''});
    }
  });

});
```

Получилось таким образом:

```
var topPos = $('#my_search_bar').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() { 
var top = $(document).scrollTop(),
pip = $('.footer').offset().top;
height = $('#my_search_bar').outerHeight();
if (top > topPos && top < pip - height) {$('#my_search_bar').addClass('fixed').removeAttr("style");}
else if (top > pip - height) {$('#my_search_bar').removeClass('fixed').css({'position':'absolute','bottom':'400px'});}
else {$('#my_search_bar').removeClass('fixed');}
})
```

;

Comment: @Alexander Masan, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В свое врем мне [помогли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/271912/html-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E).  Вот один из [примеров](http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/wXFB9/).

Comment: спасибо, что-то похожее, но что-то у меня не работает, было бы хорошо, уже в существующий код, добавить параметр который определит когда диву стоит остановится. Пока буду искать причину, почему этот скрипт у меня не работает.